# Find element using explicit wait within another element

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I have the following code:

```
List<MobileElement> messages = driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble")); //find all messages
MobileElement lastMessage = messages.get (messages.size () - 1); //get last message

// xpath query to check if the message is delivered
String xpathDeliveryStatus = ".//*[contains(@resource-id, 'delivered_indicator') or contains(@resource-id, 'read_indicator') or contains(@resource-id, 'sent_indicator')]"; 
MobileElement deliveryStatus = lastMessage.findElement (By.xpath (xpathDeliveryStatus));
```

I want to do the same except that I want to find the `deliveryStatus` variable using explicit wait. 
So I want to find the `deliveryStatus` variable inside the `lastMessage` variable using 
 `wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.locator))`

How can I do this?

I don't want to do it using one immense Xpath. Besides, I don't even know how to find the last element with the id `body_bubble` using *Xpath*, as the number of these elements is not fixed and always changing.

***P.S.*** For example, in Python we can define `WebDriverWait` with an element in the constructor instead of driver: 
`WebDriverWait(webelement, self.timeout)`

Unfortunately, it does not work in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Java documentation on ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-), it looks like we can use `presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy` to add explicit wait on the child element:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

WebElement childElem = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(lastMessage, By.xpath(xpathDeliveryStatus)));
```

Comment: Thank you!
Also find out that I can use something like this: 
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf (lastMessage.findElement (By.xpath(xpathDeliveryStatus))));`

Comment: Glad to hear this worked for you. `ExpectedConditions` class is quite flexible across all languages.